# Error creating Trigger After Insert in Mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert-update

I'm stuck when creating my trigger in mysql (on phpmyadmin), and that's why I come to ask for your help

I have 2 tables : Assemblage and Bicyclette.

## Tables Diagram:

Assemblage was built like this :

```
CREATE TABLE `Assemblage` (  
 `ID_Assemblage` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
 `Nom_Assemblage` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
 `Grandeur_Assemblage` enum('Dames','Hommes','Garçons','Filles','Adultes','Jeunes') NOT NULL,  
 `Cadre_Assemblage` varchar(10) NOT NULL,  
 `Guidon_Assemblage` varchar(10) NOT NULL,  
 `Freins_Assemblage` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,  
 `Selle_Assemblage` varchar(10) NOT NULL,  
 `DerailleurAvant_Assemblage` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,  
 `DerailleurArriere_Assemblage` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,  
 `RoueAvant_Assemblage` varchar(10) NOT NULL,  
 `RoueArriere_Assemblage` varchar(10) NOT NULL,  
 `Reflecteurs_Assemblage` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,  
 `Pedalier_Assemblage` varchar(10) NOT NULL,  
 `Ordinateur_Assemblage` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,  
 `Panier_Assemblage` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,  
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Assemblage`)  
)
```

And here Bicyclette :

```
CREATE TABLE `Bicyclette` (  
 `ID_Bicyclette` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
 `ID_Assemblage` int(11) NOT NULL,  
 `Prix_Bicyclette` float NOT NULL,  
 `Categorie_Bicyclette` enum('VTT','Vélo de course','Classique','BMX') NOT NULL,  
 `DateIntroduction_Bicyclette` date NOT NULL,  
 `DateFin_Bicyclette` date NOT NULL,  
`Nom_Bicyclette` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,    
 `Grandeur_Bicyclette` 
 enum('Dames','Hommes','Garçons','Filles','Adultes','Jeunes') DEFAULT NULL,   
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Bicyclette`),  
 KEY `ID_Assemblage` (`ID_Assemblage`),  
 CONSTRAINT `ID_Assemblage` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Assemblage`) REFERENCES `Assemblage` (`ID_Assemblage`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

## Trigger Action :

I would like that when a new row is inserted into Bicyclette with as values :

- the foreign key referring to a row of Assemblage
- the values of the all the others attributes except 'Nom_Bicyclette' and 'Grandeur_Bicyclette' which will be null.

that a Trigger inserts 'Nom_Bicyclette' and 'Grandeur_Bicyclette' with the corresponding data from Assemblage thanks to the Foreign Key *ID_Assemblage*

Here is an example of inserting data into Bicyclette:

INSERT INTO Bicyclette VALUES (102, 547.8, "VTT", 01/01/2022, 01/01/2023)

Where **102** is the assembly model in the table Assemblage.
So i would like my Trigger to perform this action (for this example):

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR  
DECLARE @size VARCHAR  

@name = SELECT Nom_Assemblage FROM Assemblage WHERE ID_Assemblage = 102  
@size = SELECT Grandeur_Assemblage FROM Assemblage WHERE ID_Assemblage = 102  

UPDATE Bicyclette SET Nom_Bicyclette=@name, Grandeur_Bicyclette=@size 
WHERE ID_Bicyclette = INSERTED.ID_Bicyclette
```

Here is a diagram to better visualize the desired effect :
[Schema for trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BerXq.png)

Thank you in advance for your help!

(It may seem special, but I have to have the fields 'Nom_Bicyclette' and 'Grandeur_Bicyclette' which correspond to the Foreign Key ID_Assemblage in my Bicyclette Table.)

Comment: Start an SQL question by showing the schema for all the relevant tables. Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` for each table, and paste it into the questions as text (NOT A PICTURE). 
An example of the data contained in these tables is also very useful. 
If at all possible create a SQLFiddle with the schema defined and some test data provided.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I edited my post accordingly, hoping that the problem is more clear and understandable.

Sorry for the formatting errors, I often come to his forum but this question was my first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create trigger Bicyclette_copy_attributes 
before insert on Bicyclette
for each row begin
  declare name varchar(255);
  declare size varchar(255);

  select Nom_Assemblage, Grandeur_Assemblage into name, size from Assemblage
  where ID_Assemblage = NEW.ID_Assemblage;

  set NEW.Nom_Bicyclette = name;

  set NEW.Grandeur_Bicyclette = size;
end
```

In MySQL, there are differences in the syntax from other brands of SQL database:

- `DECLARE` variables do not use the `@` sigil.
- Use a `BEFORE` trigger if you need to change columns in the inserted row. If you write an `AFTER` trigger, it is too late, because the row has already been inserted.
- Change columns with `SET NEW.<column>`, not `UPDATE`. The `NEW` keyword references the row that is about to be inserted.
- All statements in the body of the trigger need to be terminated with a semicolon (`;`).

Also read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html if you are using the MySQL client to execute the `create trigger`, so you understand how to set the delimiter.

Comment: The creation of the trigger did not produce any error! Thank you for your answer.
I just tried it and it works.
I understood why it is necessary to modify the values before the insert, it seems logical now!